# Pre-trained English language models

Tags: datasets, language-models

I am looking for pre-trained, downloadable English language models. Where can I find some good ones?

Comment: I see no reasons to close this question, although there is space for improvement: Should the language model be usable with a certain tool, what kind of language model are you interested in?

Comment: @jknappen Regarding the format: there should be some way (API, some open format, etc.) to use the language model in some application I write. E.g. Dragon NaturallySpeaking does have a trained, downloadable English language model, but it cannot be used in some other applications (at least without some good amount of data digging). Regarding the model: any model is fine, RNN, Kneser-Ney, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one from the LINDAT/CLARIN repository (for a specialised domain, but Open Data):

[ATCC: Pronunciation lexicon and n-gram counts for ASR module](https://lindat.mff.cuni.cz/repository/xmlui/handle/11858/00-097C-0000-000D-EC92-F)